# How to initialise Spring AnnotationConfigApplicationContext inside @BeforeTest in Testng?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testng, spring-test

I have a testng+spring suite with parallel option set to Tests. I would like to have each `<test>` have it's own ApplicationContext. So each `<test>` thread will have their own set of beans. I am able to initialise the ApplicationContext but the beans are not getting autowired and I am getting nullpointer exception when I am trying to access the bean. Please find my code below,

**AppTest.class**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.comp.automation")
public class AppTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

    @BeforeTest
    public void intialise() throws Exception{
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanTwo.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public CommonBean commonBean;

    @Autowired
    public BeanTwo beanTwo;

    @Parameters(value={"param"})
    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue(String param) {
        System.out.println(commonBean.STRING_CHECK);
        commonBean.createCommonBeanObject(param);
        System.out.println("Checking the bean values now...");
        assertTrue( true );

    }
}
```

**CommonBean.class**

```
@Component
public class CommonBean {

    public String commonBeanValue;
    public String STRING_CHECK = "Hello!!";

    public void createCommonBeanObject(String param){
        commonBeanValue = param;
    }

    public void printParamValue(){
        System.out.println(commonBeanValue);
    }

}
```

**BeanTwo.class**

```
@Component
public class BeanTwo{

public void printBeanTwo(){
        System.out.println("Bean Two!!");
    }

}
```

Can someone help me with this and point me in the right direction?

Comment: For not shared test context spring have `@DirtiesContext`. But if you do not want using it, you can set `context` as class field and initialize in `@BeforeTest` method. After that in each test method you can easily using `context.getBean(...)`

Comment: Hi @borino, I cannot have context as a class field. A single <test> will have multiple classes inside them and there will be multiple <test> inside a single test <suite>. I want a context per <test> which will be shared across multiple classes. Each <test> will be run in a separate thread by testng. Hence having a context as a class field will not help me in this scenario. Testng.xml structure will be like, <suite><test><classes><class name="class1"><class name="class2"></class></classes></test><test><classes><class name="class1"><class name="class2"></class></classes></test></suite>

Comment: You are working around Spring Test instead of using it. Spring should already take care of that, have you actually tried the regular spring support before you started working on your own. And instantiating a context is hardly enough, there needs a lot more to be done to make it work.

Comment: I tried using Spring support for the TestNG Class. But I was not able to implement multithreading for a Spring Managed TestNG class. Though I marked the <test> to run in parallel as a part of TestNG Configuration, Spring managed <test> got executed sequentially. That is the reason why I would like to initialize the spring beans inside @BeforeTest, so that it can be managed by the TestNG Thread. Could you give me a working example where Spring supports multithreading, where each thread has a separate ApplicationContext?

Comment: @M.Deinum please find my comment above

Comment: testng is in charge of executing in parallel, that has nothing to do with the use of the spring test framework.Also trying to manage those things won't work, as there is a lot more the test context does to make tests work (transaction setup, injection, test events, etc.) Instead make your test-suite multithreaded and make sure everything runs in its own process (probably a forked JVM) then you will receive a context per executed test.  If that isn't going to work for you, then don't use autowiring or the test support all together but write your test methods like that.

Comment: Also when running make sure that you are running your suite NOT your individual test class as that will ignore the suite .